# Why use averages vs medians in statistics?

Tags: statistics, average, median

Why in statistics is the average used instead of the median, why are P values for example always calculated with averages and not with median?

I have always been taught that stats and P values always have to be used with the average
and I have no idea why, is it just a systemic choice of the person who created the data or can they be used interchangeably for the majority of statistical work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by calculating a p-value with an average. Can you give an example of what you have in mind?

Answer (score 3):

The $p$-values that are calculated typically rely on the assumption that the data studied are well represented by a specific model. This is often assumed to be the normal distribution that is parameterised by its mean and standard deviation.

The mathematical derivations to produce $p$-values are much more straightforward when making this kind of model assumption (i.e. one that relies use of the mean).

The median is an example of an *order* statistic. It definitely has nice properties as a summary measure for a data set (e.g. not too sensitive to outliers) but it is harder to use it in a model that can in turn be used to produce $p$-values.

Comment: +1, The median has it's advantages, but many times the mean is easier to use. As an additional point, the sample mean is often "sufficient" for the data. I don't know of any distribution where the median is sufficient.